# edit grub2 to boot other partition

Tags: grub2, partitioning, boot-partition

I was running out of space on my primary partition that I had originally set to 30gb (I know, rookie mistake), but it was at the end of the disk so a resize operation would be more data loss prone than anything, so I copied my root partition to a much larger partition at the beginning of the disk with gparted, and that worked fine using a grub boot disk to boot it, though I don't want to have to have a disk in my drive every time I turn my computer on, plus the simulated bios was making the wireless card unrecognizable. Right now, I want to get my computer to boot into the other partition, as it's not even showing up in the grub menu. I'm really new to linux (about half a year in actual experience) and need almost all instructions to be simple and concise (although a little explanation of why is fine). I want to add a boot entry to the grub menu on the mbr that boots to /dev/sda5 instead of /dev/sda2 if you need other numbers or some kind of terminal log or anything, please tell me, but make sure to tell me how. Yes, I know, there is a great possibility that this is a "duplicate", but none of the other ones made sense to me.

edit: PLEASE HELP! I know that other methods could have worked somewhat more effectively, but now I just want to get it working in the configuration it is in. I don't want a speech about how I did it wrong, I just need directions, either that can scan all partitions for bootloaders and have them point to /dev/sda5 or so that I can change the names/mount names so that what is now dev/sda5 would be dev/sda2 so the bootloader the computer is using (wherever it is) is pointing to the partition I want to boot from.

Comment: Did you consider moving a partition other than root to the larger partition? It seems unlikely that that 30GB was evenly distributed among all the directories. Did you have /home on the same partition? If so, moving just it may have been a better approach.

Comment: I didn't want to experience corruption, and I want to run my entire installation off of a single partition to make it more portable and  easier to back up. Running all my stuff from separate partitions also gives the possibility for more mount errors. also I just didn't want to have to deal with the addedd complexity.

Comment: Those are reasons to split a bit more: it reduces the scope of corruption (and makes it easier to react to if it does happen), and easier to back up. And simpler in some ways. One can make good arguments for and against splitting, but if I was out of space on an existing system, I'd definitely split off /home and maybe something else rather than risk something going wrong in resizing.

Comment: I didn't want to have to worry about the home partition becoming corrupted WHILE moving it

Comment: Ah. Don't move it, redefine it: Make a copy of your current /home on the new partition. Then change fstab to use it. If something has gone wrong, change back your fstab and start again. If all is well, temporarily mount the old /home and delete it. At no point do you risk corruption happening that can't be detected and recovered from immediately.
I'd be much more worried about corruption in a resize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct me if I'm misunderstanding your question, but have you tried booting into a Ubuntu live CD and running boot-repair?  It helps fix booting problems like missing boot partitions.

http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks! That was even easier than what I had in mind! I just booted  into the other (nearly full) partition and installed boot-repair; it worked like a charm, and added both partitions to the boot menu, but the partition I wanted to boot from was at the top of the list, so now I don't even have to change that around! Now how do I theme the Grub2 it installed to the mbr? It's not exactly a "mounted volume" in ubuntu.

Comment: @sbergeron I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "theme" it.  If you hit 'e' when the system boots, you can edit Grub's config, if that's what you mean

Comment: Grub customizer, for instance, allows changing icons and colors for  grub installed to the local partition, new versions of grub for instance sometimes have different resources, like one version of grub comes, by default, with a debian logo next to/above a picture of the earth, another version had a dark maroon/purple background and white text and selector highlighting.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how to do that.  You're only going to see it for a few seconds a day anyway.  Remember, Google is your friend

Comment: Sorry but it's still not working. I run boot-repair and it fixes the boot process for a total of three boots then it boots to the other partition and I have to run it again

Comment: I really need help with this, i am unable to boot my full partition, I can only boot the old, full, one. Please help quickly!

Comment: It works sometimes not others, I really need a more stable option though

Comment: Go into your BIOS and make sure grub is first on the boot list, and if it is, run boot-repair again, but look in the advanced options section and see if anything useful is unchecked.  Other than that, I'm not sure if I can give you anymore advice. Sorry for the slow response, I never saw your other comments

Comment: my bios doesn't show anything other than 'boot hard disk' floppy disk, network, cd...blah blah blah, nothing that boots any particular partition. thanks for the help, it was much appreciated and I wouldn't have gotten this far if not for you

Comment: No problem.  I wish I could help more though.  Don't forget to try the advanced options